# ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 32)

Tags: deep-learning, keras

```
inp=Input(shape=(max_length,))
x = Embedding(nb_words, EMBEDDING_DIM, embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),input_length=max_length, trainable=False)(inp)
x = SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(x)
x = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM, return_sequences=True))(x)
x = Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
inp1 = Input(shape=(2,))
concat = concatenate([x, inp1])
x = Dense(32, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')(concat)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[inp, inp1], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

when i try to fit the above model it gives me the value error

```
history = model.fit([X_train_pad, x], y_train, batch_size=1024, epochs=2, validation_data=([X_test_pad, x1], y_test))
```

Here max_length is 256 and i pad the input data with max_length.

Comment: From the code you provided, it looks like you are giving an `x` to model.fit() which is a Tensor, not real data. Please provide a definition of data which you give to model.fit() and also a full stack trace.

Comment: Actually i assigned the data in the variable x thank you

Comment: Please provide a full error trace.